# Python beginner - even though both variables have the same value, this if statement will not accept them as equal

Tags: python

```
task = input("would you like to register(a),take a test(b)or check you scores(c)?")
if task == "a":
    username = (input("what do you want as a username?") + input("what year were you born?"))
    print("your user name is:"+username)
    password = input("what do you want as a password?")
    yeargroup = input("what year group are you in?")
    with open(username+".txt","w") as file:
        file.write(username)
        file.write("\n" )
        file.write(password)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(yeargroup)
```

this first part works just fine and writes to the file correctly

```
elif task == "b":
    username = input("what is your username?")
    with open(username+".txt", "r") as file:
        lines=file.readlines()
        password = input("what is your password?")
        password = password.lower()
        passwordline = lines[1]
        print(password)
        print(passwordline)
```

i just added this part to make sure that the strings were equal in value they were and the if statement below still wouldn't work.

```
       if str(passwordline) == str(password):
            print("welcome.")
        else:
            print("invalid password")
```

Comment: Try `print(repr(passwordline))`, there’s probably a newline character at the end of it so those strings *aren’t* equal.

Answer (score 0):

The following works and is something i regularly use as a base... Feel free to re purpose it to your needs

```
import time
"""
---------
Logged in
---------
"""
# Function for when the user succesfully logs in 
def LoggedIn():
    print("You are now logged in, since this has not completed we will log you out")


"""
---------
Menu
---------
"""
# The Menu
def Menu():
# Welcomes the user
    print("Hello and welcome to Smart Systems Account management system")
# Asks the user if they want to login or create a account
    choice = input("Would you like to login or create a account?")
# if the user selects login
    if choice.lower() == "login":
# call the Login Function
        Login()
# if the user selects create
    elif choice.lower() == "create":
# call the create function
        Create()
# if the user inputs neither login or create
    else:
# Tells the user that what they inputted is incorrect
# and tells them to type login or create
        print("That is not a valid option")
        print("Type 'Login' or 'Create'")

"""
---------
Create account
---------
"""
# Account creation function
def Create():
# Open the Logins.txt file in append mode
    file = open("Logins.txt", "a")
# Ask user for their username
    username = input("Input username")
# ask user for their password
    password = input("Input password")
# asks user for their password again
    password2 = input("Input password again")
# If the two passwords match, are over or equal to 6 characters, Contains capital leters and isnot just alphabetical
    if password == password2 and len(password) >= 6 and password != password.lower() and password.isalpha() == False:
# save the users details to the file in a new line with a commer seperating them
        file.write('\n'+username+","+password+",")
# close the file
        file.close()
# tell the user account creation was a success
        print("Account has been created")
#take them back to the menu
        Menu()
# if the password does not match the requirements
    else:
# tell them the password is incorrect
        print("Password does not have letters and numbers or Password does not have capitals or Password is not 6 or more letters long or Passwords do not match")
# close the file
        file.close()
# take them back to the menu
        Menu()

"""
---------
Login Code
---------
"""
# Login function
def Login():
# Sets correct to false (Will explain below)
    Correct = False
# while correct = false then keep looping (Will be set to true when they get it correct)
    while Correct == False:
# open your file (Logins.txt is the file name in read mode (r))
        file = open("Logins.txt", "r")
# ask for username
        username = input("input username : ")
# ask for password
        password = input("input password : ")
# for each line in Logins.txt
        for line in file:
# Split each word that is inbetween commers into seperate variables
            details =line.split(",")
# Details 0 is username and Details 1 is password
# if username is same as file and password is same
            if username == details[0] and password == details[1]:
# set correct = true
                Correct = True
# set users name to login
                login = details[0]
# close file
                file.close()
# Break form the for loop
                break
# if its incorrect
            else:
# set a useless var to anything so it dosn't raise a error
                pointlessvar = 1
# if correct == True
    if Correct == True:
# Login user
        LoggedIn()
# else
    else:
# print incorrect
        print("incorrect")


"""
---------
Main non function code
---------
"""
# create a continus loop
while True == True:
# call the choice function
    Menu()
```